# How can I find the EXACT amount of matching words in a string?

Tags: javascript

for a project I've written a function which includes the following:

```
var filtering_words = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'];

//finding matching words
var prohibited_words = filtering_words;
for (var i = 0; i < prohibited_words.length; i++) {
  if (value.indexOf(prohibited_words[i]) > -1) {
    user_report['matching_words'].push(prohibited_words[i]);
    user_report['matching_words_amount'] = user_report['matching_words'].length;
  } 
}
```

String: 'alpha beta beta gamma'

For now I just get all the matching words.
So my result would look like that: ['alpha'], ['beta'], ['gamma']

But I would also like to know how often a "filtering_word" is in my string. In this case I would want to know that there are actually 2 betas...

Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: You can use `array#filter` to find out the occurrences of `value`. `user_report['matching_words_amount'] = filtering_words.filter(word => word === value).length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the results in an `Object` instead of an `Array`, so that you could map the filtered word to the number of occurrences.

To find the number of occurrences, use a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the [`g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags) to get an array of all occurrences (and `i` flag for a case insensitive search), then get the resulting array length.

```js
var user_report = { matching_words: {} }
var value = 'lambdabetaalphabeta'
var filtering_words = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'];

var prohibited_words = filtering_words;
for (var i = 0; i < prohibited_words.length; i++) {
   var matches = (value.match(new RegExp(prohibited_words[i], 'ig')) || []).length
   if (matches) {
     var matching_words = user_report['matching_words'] || {};
     matching_words[prohibited_words[i]] = matches
   }
}
user_report['matching_words_amount'] = Object.keys(user_report['matching_words']).length

console.log(user_report)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you the 'unnecessary' words:

```js
let arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'beta'];       
   for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){    
       for(let j = 0;j < arr.length;j++){        
           if(i !== j){    
              if(arr[i] === arr[j]){    
                  let [sameWords] = arr.splice(i, 1)   
                  console.log(sameWords)   
              }    
           }    
       }       
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to populate a dictionary with prohibited words and their frequencies:

```
var str = "alpha beta yo alpha beta lorem ipsum gamma alpha", 
    filtering_words = ['alpha', 'beta', 'beta', 'gamma'];

// divide the str into words, then check if a word is prohibited and add (increment) it to the dictionary 
var result = str.split(' ').reduce(function(acc,v)
{
  if (filtering_words.indexOf(v)>=0)
  {
    acc[v] = (acc[v] || 0) + 1; 
  }
  return acc
},{})

console.log(result)
// {alpha: 3, beta: 2, gamma: 1}
```

Comment: I like how this works but unfortunately it does not ensure that my string contains a space as a separator. So I would miss results in strings like "lambdabetaalphabeta".